# How does LinkedList work internally in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

As far as I know, the concept of a linked list is a bunch of object connected to each other by having a 'next' and sometimes 'previous' attribute to traverse the objects.

I noticed in Java, you can create a LinkedList object...but treat it like an array/list/sequence by using the same methods such as .add(), .get(), etc.

So, is LinkedList internally an array-like sequence?

Comment: If you want to see the implementation, look for the source code of `java.util.LinkedList` which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

Comment: Or look at the source: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Comment: You may be interested in my [Internal Life of LinkedList in java](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/05/internal-life-of-linkedlist-in-java.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, is LinkedList internally an array-like sequence?

No. It's a series of instances of a private nested class `Entry`, which has `next`, `previous` and `element` references. Note that you could have found this out yourself by looking at the source code, which comes with the JDK.

The reason why this internal structure is not exposed is that it prevents the structure from becoming corrupted and e.g. containing a loop. And the uniform access via the `List` and `Deque` interfaces allows polymorphic use.

Comment: +1: The list which is internally an array-like sequence is called ArrayList. ;)

Comment: -1: It depends on your programming skill I guess. From the wikipedia article on Linked Lists: "It can also be slow, and with a naïve allocator, wasteful, to allocate memory separately for each new element, a problem generally solved using memory pools." -- FYI, memory pools are the arrays that pros use to internally store linked lists. They are also known as slab allocators.

Comment: @Anthony: revenge downvote, eh? Get over it. Skilled pros don't get into internet-hairpulling over what level a question should be answered on.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Absolutely not. I agree that your answer of "no" is correct in most applications and implementations, but not all. You can actually implement linked-lists with arrays as the underlying data structure, in cases where performance is a concern -- as the wikipedia article says.

Comment: @Anthony Blake The question is about the **specific** implementation of LinkedList class provided by the Java Collection API. An array-based implementation is `ArrayList` as Peter stated before in his comment here.

Comment: @Anthony: sure, but the question was about the Java standard API class LinkedList, which does not use arrays. The JVM may, but if you insist to "go deeper", you may just as well start talking aobut how the "contiguous memory" of an array really isn't because in order to improve performance, it's interleaved between physical RAM modules and again between individual chips-

Comment: @Fatal It seems you are unaware that there is more than one implementation of the java Collection API.. have you heard of Android? Go and check the Android source code for the LinkedList versus the source code linked above. So no, the OP didn't specify a specific implementation. And no, an array based implementation isn't necessarily an arraylist -- I'll try this one last time: believe it or not, you can build a linked-list with chunks of arrays. I have done this because you get some of the advantages of arrays (speed), with some of the advantages of linkedlists (arbitrary insertions).

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Can we agree that there isn't one implementation of LinkedList for the Java standard library? (if not, you should probably call Oracle and tell them they can stop suing Google). I fully agree that all java implementations of that LinkedList class *probably* are just linked-lists -- but that doesn't mean you can't write your own that is a hybrid between an array and a linkedlist (or that someone hasn't already..).

Answer (score 5):

A LinkedList in Java works just as you would expect it to do. If you use the official Collections [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) then it will indeed be a *a bunch of object connected to each other by having a 'next' and sometimes 'previous'*.

And yes, it has a `get(int index)` method which is surprising because it would not be very efficient as you would need to start at the beginning and count your way up the list to find the `index`th entry and this is not what LinkedLists are good at. The reason it is there is because LinkedList implements the [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. This is something you can with ALL lists.

However, you would probably try to avoid using a LinkedList when most of your access to it is through the `get(int index)` method as that would clearly be most inefficient. You would be perhaps better to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 4):

LinkedList is a chain of entities in which every entity knows about next-one,
so get(index) operation requires iterating over this chain with counter.
But this list optimized for adding and deleting by position (in case when I need to put element inside list or delete element from middle linked list performs better)

Answer (score 2):

as i know linkedlist is like what you said in the first paragraph. each object has two references, called it's previous and it's next.
unlike array which works sequentially (in C it's exactly stored in sequence. i think java just does the same, that's why we can't re-size an array), list works by referencing. so logically it works slower than array does.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement an object that works like an array, using a linked list. Compared to arrays, some operations will be faster and some will be slower. For example, calling `get()` for an element near the end might be quite a lot slower with a linked list than with an array. But, it's still possible.

On the other hand, deleting an element from the middle of a linked list will be faster than the corresponding operation done using arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Linked list is provided by the collection and by good design you could create a double linked list. Now it is not like array because these objects will not have indexes and are not elements within the container i.e. list. Hence you go through defining the next and previous and dictate what the next move is. They all have the same methods because again they are collections like i said.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is LinkedList internally an array-like sequence?

**NO** It is Doubly-linked list implementation.

Answer (score -8):

Internally it will be using what is called a 'slab allocator' -- this is basically a linked list of small arrays. Each time you add an object, it checks if there is space in the slab, and if so, puts the object there. Otherwise, it allocates a new slab and puts the object in the first element of the slab.

This technique minimizes memory allocation overheads -- if you add a lot of items to a linked list, that would be a lot of small memory allocations which take a lot of time, and the slab allocators minimize that

Comment: This is simply wrong. Java is not C++. Small allocations are fast. Consequently, the API implementation does not use any tricks to avoid it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Where do you think the JVM gets the memory for each object it allocates? Do you think the JVM is calling malloc() every time? Garbage collectors work with memory in slabs. Please explain how you think Java is allocating memory for linked lists without slabs of memory.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt From documentation about IBM's JVM: "These sections are typically implemented as contiguous slabs of native memory that are under the control of the Java memory manager (which includes the garbage collector)."

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt lol @ "Small allocations are fast" -- they are only fast in Java because the JVM has been allocating *slabs* of native memory.

Comment: @Anthony Blake The question was about how they work internally in Java, not how the JVM is allocating memory. How this works depends on JVM implementation and is normally not the point of interest of the programmer who wants to decide using LinkedList or not and therefore want to understand how it is implemented with all advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Fatal I explained how they work internally. A programmer needs to know about the costs and benefits, and in this case, you can't properly evaluate the cost without knowing a little about how it works. You shouldn't treat the JVM as some magic black box that only scientists in white lab coats know about -- knowing a little about how the JVM and the computer works allows a programmer to estimate the performance of a given approach.

Comment: @Anthony Blake Then why do not even go deeper and explain how malloc() works? What JVM implementation do you use as reference? There exist 8 KiB JVMs, too. These are implemented VERY simple. You're simply stepping too deep for answering the question here. You're right when you say that it is good to know how some things work on most common JVMs, but it is not of interest for questions like this one here.

Comment: @Fatal The vast majority of people are using a JVM's on desktop/server machines, where performance relies on the JVM efficiently managing memory that is on the order of MB or GB. So I think we can safely assume the OP wasn't using an 8 KiB JVM.

Comment: The fact remains that this has nothing to do with the implementation of linked lists in Java. JVM internals were not part of the question.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt OK, admittedly it doesn't have a lot to do with most implementations and applications. The question was "is LinkedList internally an array-like sequence" -- to which the answer is: it *could* be, if you were concerned about performance. The OP didn't actually specify any specific implementation, so I don't think "no" is the right answer. But I'll admit that "no" is the right answer in most cases.